# How to correctly copy image from UIImagePickerController?

Tags: ios, image, uiimagepickercontroller

From this [article](https://turbofuture.com/cell-phones/Access-Photo-Camera-and-Library-in-Swift), I'm learning to take picture / choose from library, and put the result in a UIImageView.

```
@IBOutlet var theImage: UIImageView!;

@IBAction func openLibrary (sender: UIButton) {
    if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.PhotoLibrary) {
        let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
        imagePicker.delegate = self
        imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.PhotoLibrary;
        imagePicker.allowsEditing = true
        self.presentViewController(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}

func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingImage image: UIImage!, editingInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]!) {
    theImage.image = image;
    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil);
}
```

The result is like this:

Before click on the select from library
[image: Before click on the select from library]

While selecting the image
[image: While selecting the image]

Image picker result
[image: Image Result]

The image like cropped, even though I have set the mode to be Aspect Fit. What's wrong?

EDIT:

Scale to fit? This is all I have on the image mode:

[image: Image mode]

Comment: change mode to scale to fit. @Chen Li Yong

Comment: Scale to fill. @Chen Li Yong